# Multiple send() method calls and 1 receive method. Is this normal?

Tags: sockets, network-programming

If on the client side I connect to a server and invoke the `Send()` method on the socket sending short data many times, is it normal that the server sometimes receives only one 'packet' which contains all the accumulated data which is the sum of many sending methods?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the received stream from a socket limited to a single send command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252039/is-the-received-stream-from-a-socket-limited-to-a-single-send-command)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. TCP is a stream, there's no concept of an individual "packet" - you should expect to receive everything one byte at a time, everything merged together or anything in between.

The only guarantees are that no data will be lost, and that it'll arrive in the same order you sent it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, that is completely normal, for TCP stream-based sockets anyway. By default, the [Nagle algorithm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms817942.aspx) for send coalescing is enabled, which reduces the number of packets that are transmitted in a small amount of time. You have to disable the algorithm if you want each `send()` to transmit its own packet. Sometimes that is needed in special circumstances, but usually the default behavior is adequate and desirable for most socket uses.

Comment: Even if you disable Nagle you may get multiple `send()`s in a single receive buffer, e.g. because multiple IP datagrams arrived before the receiving process was scheduled, or because they were sent in one IP datagram due to retransmission or the send window being full.